Use a Lisp to identify whether a given sequence exists within a binary stream
Using standard Common Lisp techniques (libraries acceptable if they offer easier or quicker possibilities), what would be the analogous way to do (search "bar" "foobarbaz"), where "bar" is a given sequence of bytes and "foobarbaz" is the stream? Specifically, I am trying to search in a file that I have opened as (unsigned-byte 8). It would be helpful to know where the characters I am looking for (4d 54 68 64) are located within the file.
I know that the analogy breaks down because a stream is not the same kind of object as a collection. But there's got to be a relatively straightforward way to do this reading out some of the contents of a file I've opened using with-open-file.
I have combed the CL Cookbook and Practical Common Lisp, which has a great section on reading/writing binary files, but I couldn't quite figure out a quick and dirty solution for this.
EDIT:
I've updated the title to reflect a more general purpose: using any Lisp to solve this problem. Many of the solutions posted here for doing so using Common Lisp represent valuable examples of accomplishing this task, but the simplest solution appears to be using Racket and "ports" along with the built-in support for regular expressions. For Racket reference:
https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ports.html
https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html
https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/regexp.html

If you're looking for an N-byte sequence, create an N-byte buffer. Read the first N bytes into the buffer, check if it matches. Then read the rest of the stream 1 byte at a time, appending to the buffer and removing the first character. Check if this matches.

@barmar That sounds relatively straightforward--I guess it involves looping and calling read-byte. I tried a few examples using make-sequence and calling read-sequence repeatedly "by hand", but I don't have a lot of experience managing buffers, so I'm not sure how to wrap it all up into a single function call. There's an example section of ANSI Common Lisp that treats buffers in a "string substitution" context. It would be great to see a simpler example of working with such a queue, perhaps with typically Lisp-y recursion.

It would be trivial to do in Racket if you're willing to consider other languages...

@Shawn Seeing an answer in Racket could be helpful, at least as a point of comparison.

Something like (call-with-input-file "foo.txt" (lambda (in) (regexp-match? (regexp-quote #"\x4d\x54\x68\x64") in)) #:mode 'binary) (Racket regular expression functions can take an input port (stream in CL) as the data source to match against, not just strings)

Wow, yes--that would appear to be trivially easy, as you say. I appreciate everyone's help trying to write a whole mini-program...that effectively has already been written by Racket folks. I wonder if I should edit the question so that this could be an answer and not just a comment.

@Shawn I think the Racket approach is by far the simplest; if you'd like to post it as an answer, I'm happy to accept it as an answer.

@PlinySuetonious -- it is generally frowned upon to substantially change a question after answers arrive.

Asking for solutions in "any Lisp [sic]" is too broad. And offering to accept an answer from a drive-by commenter in a language not originally asked about, after others have expended significant effort to answer your original question, is in poor taste at the very least.

@ad-absurdum I do apologize for my poor taste. StackOverflow questions are, for me, 1) places to learn about programming techniques and 2) places to efficaciously solve problems; my change of title reflects that. I was literally writing in a middle school classroom where I was trying to solve that problem with students waiting to enter, so efficacy was paramount. Regardless, I've accepted your answer as a gesture of good will.

One way you could do this is to read from the stream to fill a buffer repeatedly, searching the buffer for the desired sequence until it is found or until the stream is exhausted. Each time the buffer is filled and searched without finding a match, the last n bytes, where n is the number of bytes in the sought sequence, have already been checked. So the last n-1 bytes will need to be checked after replenishing the buffer. This can be done by moving the last n-1 bytes to the front of the buffer before refilling it from the stream.
The example code below defines a stream-find function that takes a needle argument which represents the sought sequence, a stream argument which represents the stream to be searched, and a buffer-length argument which defaults to 1024. It uses an array of unsigned bytes for a buffer. keep is the number of bytes to be kept between buffer refills, and refill-length is the number of fresh bytes to be searched after each refill. If the needle sequence is larger than the buffer an error is raised.
A local function check-buffer is created which is recursively called to fill the buffer and search for the needle. The check-buffer function takes a keeping argument which tracks the number of bytes kept from the previous search, and a checked argument which tracks the total number of bytes searched so far. These are both zero for the first call of check-buffer.
When check-buffer is called it copies the end of the buffer to the front of the buffer if the call is keeping bytes from a previous search. Then the contents of the stream are read into the buffer starting from the last kept byte. Then the buffer is searched for needle, and the resulting position is saved in found.
If needle was found, the found position is combined with the number of bytes previously checked to return the byte position of needle in the stream. If the call to read-sequence terminated before reaching the end of the buffer the stream was exhausted without finding needle, so it was not in the stream and nil is returned. Otherwise the stream is not exhausted, so check-buffer is called again, keeping n-1 bytes from the end of the buffer and updating the number of bytes in checked.
(defun stream-find (needle stream &key (buffer-length 1024))
  (let* ((buffer (make-array buffer-length
                             :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
         (needle-length (length needle))
         (keep (- needle-length 1))
         (refill-length (- buffer-length keep)))
    (when (> needle-length buffer-length)
      (error "buffer must be able to contain needle"))
    (labels ((check-buffer (keeping checked)
               (when (> keeping 0)                         ; copy end of buffer to front
                 (map-into buffer #'identity
                           (subseq buffer refill-length)))
               (let ((last (read-sequence buffer stream :start keeping)) ; fill buffer
                     (found (search needle buffer)))                     ; search buffer
                 (cond (found (+ found checked))                         ; found it
                       ((< last buffer-length) nil)                      ; not found
                       (t (check-buffer keep
                                        (+ checked refill-length)))))))  ; keep looking
      (check-buffer 0 0))))

Here are a few sample usages given this testfile.txt. Note that the repl code here uses the SBCL extension sb-ext:string-to-octets as a convenience to create a vector of bytes to use for a needle:
_________
__**_____
_________
__***____

CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "c:/code/lisp/scratch/testfile.txt"
                                 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
           (stream-find (sb-ext:string-to-octets "**") stream))
13

CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "c:/code/lisp/scratch/testfile.txt"
                                 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
           (stream-find (sb-ext:string-to-octets "***") stream))
35

CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "c:/code/lisp/scratch/testfile.txt"
                                 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
           (stream-find (sb-ext:string-to-octets "**") stream :buffer-length 3))
13

CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "c:/code/lisp/scratch/testfile.txt"
                                 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
           (stream-find (sb-ext:string-to-octets "**!") stream :buffer-length 3))
NIL

Finding All Matches in a File
The above solution finds the position of the first match in a stream, but you may want to find all match positions. The above can be adapted to do this. One solution is to write a find-all function that returns a list of all position matches in a sequence, and to use this instead of search in check-buffer. These lists of matches will need to be adjusted to account for the number of bytes already processed in previous batches before collecting them into a list of results.
;;; Returns a list of 0-indexed positions where `needle` was found in `stream`.
(defun stream-find-all (needle stream &key (buffer-length 1024))
  (let* ((buffer (make-array buffer-length
                             :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
         (needle-length (length needle))
         (keep (- needle-length 1))
         (refill-length (- buffer-length keep)))
    (when (> needle-length buffer-length)
      (error "buffer must be able to contain needle"))
    (labels ((check-buffer (keeping checked positions)
               (when (> keeping 0)                         ; copy end of buffer to front
                 (map-into buffer #'identity
                           (subseq buffer refill-length)))
               (let* ((last (read-sequence buffer stream :start keeping)) ; fill buffer
                      (found (find-all needle buffer last)))              ; search buffer
                 (cond (found (check-buffer keep                          ; found it
                                            (+ checked refill-length)
                                            (append positions
                                                    (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                                                                (+ x checked))
                                                            found))))
                       ((< last buffer-length) positions)         ; stream exhausted
                       (t (check-buffer keep                      ; keep looking
                                        (+ checked refill-length)
                                        positions))))))
      (check-buffer 0 0 nil))))

;;; Returns a list of 0-indexed positions where `needle` was found in `seq`.
(defun find-all (needle seq &optional (end-seq nil))
  (let ((i 0))
    (loop with last = (- (length seq) (length needle))
          when (<= i last)
            do (setf i (search needle seq :start2 i :end2 end-seq))
          when (or (null i) (> i last))
            return positions
          collect i into positions
          do (incf i))))

The stream-find-all function finds all matches in a stream, exhausting the stream before returning a list of positions. The local check-buffer function now has an accumulator argument that collects results which are taken from find-all and adjusted using mapcar to account for previously processed bytes. find-all returns a list of all match positions within the sequence it is given, but these positions are relative to that sequence, not the stream being processed.
CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "c:/code/lisp/scratch/testfile.txt"
                                 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
           (stream-find-all (sb-ext:string-to-octets "____") stream))
(0 1 2 3 4 5 15 16 22 23 24 25 26 27 38)

The Easiest Non-Library Solution
Most of the code in stream-find and stream-find-all is for managing the buffer. If you can slurp your file into a single buffer the problem becomes much simpler.
Finding the first match needs none of the above code:
CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "c:/code/lisp/scratch/testfile.txt"
                                 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
           (let ((file-contents (make-array (file-length stream)
                                            :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
             (read-sequence file-contents stream)
             (search (sb-ext:string-to-octets "**") file-contents)))
13

Finding all matches only needs the find-all function from above:
CL-USER> (with-open-file (stream "c:/code/lisp/scratch/testfile.txt"
                                 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
           (let ((file-contents (make-array (file-length stream)
                                            :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
             (read-sequence file-contents stream)
             (find-all (sb-ext:string-to-octets "**") file-contents)))
(13 35 36)

Or Use a Library
I'm sure that there are ways to improve the code above, and I agree with @ignis volens that there are likely algorithmic improvements to be found.
One virtue of using an existing library is that these problems have probably already been thought about and reasonable solutions arrived at. And using library code probably means that you will need to write less code yourself, as in the answer using the Series library by @coredump.

This is likely a better approach than mine!

@ad-absurdum A very thorough answer...I'm not sure I'm in a position to vet it as the definitive answer until I can run it and check I understand how it's working. In the meantime, it seems to me that all the answers here have something to be learned from.

@adabsurdum your answers are always amazing! Thanks for your efforts!

@Gwang-JinKim -- I appreciate the kind words :)

Here is a function which uses only naked CL features to do this.  In real life I'd probably use some better linguistic abstractions which are so easy in Lisp, but this is easy to understand.
I am suspicious that there must be a better algorithm than this: in particular this needs to check the whole string each step.  What this does is pretty much what barmar describes: make a buffer the length of the vector we're looking for.  Fill it initially, and then cycle through it replacing bytes and checking for the string each time from the current buffer index, remembering that the check must in general loop around in the buffer.
This assumes that read-byte is well-buffered: if it's not it will be horrible.  If it's not then some shim could be written using read-sequence and a big buffer (or, for non-vast files, just slurping the whole file into a buffer, searching it, and throwing it away).
The function smells slightly of fortran.  I have not tested it more than slightly (but I have tested it slightly).
(defun octet-vector-in-stream-p (vector stream)
  (declare (type (vector (unsigned-byte 8)) vector))
  (let* ((l (length vector))
         (buffer (make-array l :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
    ;; Just make it less verbose and horrible
    (flet ((fail ()
             (return-from octet-vector-in-stream-p nil))
           (succeed ()
             (return-from octet-vector-in-stream-p (- (file-position stream) l))))
      ;; If there are not enough characters in the stream we can give up now
      (unless (= (read-sequence buffer stream) l) (fail))
      ;; Loop endlessly with i cycling through the buffer
      (do ((i 0 (mod (1+ i) l)))
          (nil)
        ;; Now look for the string starting from the current buffer
        ;; index, remembering we must loop round in general
        (dotimes (j l (succeed))
          ;; The moment we don't match we can stop
          (unless (= (aref vector j) (aref buffer (mod (+ i j) l)))
            (return nil)))
        ;; put the next byte into the buffer, failing if we hit EOF
        (let ((b (read-byte stream nil nil)))
          (unless b (fail))
          (setf (aref buffer i) b))))))


your answers are always amazing! Thanks for your efforts!

Assuming a fixed-size search buffer, you can write it as follows using the SERIES package. A more generic version can be written too, using multiple-value-call and map-fn, but here I choose to show an example with a vector of size 3. This reads from the stream byte-by-byte, which could be inefficient. On the other hand, Lisp implementations are likely to implement buffering already so this might not be a problem.
(defpackage :test (:use :cl :series))
(in-package :test)

(with-open-file (in "/dev/random" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (collect-or (mapping (((a b c) (chunk 3 1 (scan-stream in #'read-byte))))
                 (equalp (list a b c) '(10 20 30)))))

The innermost scan-stream fetches bytes from the stream. They are grouped in chunks of size 3, advancing by one element (e.g. a sliding window of size 3). Each element of the chunk is then bound respectively to a, b and c inside mapping, which computes a boolean. You can even avoid building the list if you want by writing (and (= a 10) (= b 20) (= c 30)), either manually or with a macro. Finally, the stream of booleans is processed by collect-or, which stops processing the iteration as soon as the value is T (notice that we read from /dev/random here, which is infinite).
NB. As always with SERIES, everything is fused into a single loop during macroexpansion, so it is rather efficient.
If I add a counter then the amount of bytes read is typically in millions before finding a match, like 62'353'228 bytes for an execution time of 0.356s using SBCL.
